# Add Dependency Property to a Specific Control Inside a Custom Control

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I'm a beginner to WPF MVVM development and just need some help about this one. I just want to know how to add a dependency property on an specific control inside a custom control or a usercontrol.

I have a view (UserMaintenance) that uses a custom autocomplete control (UserAutoComplete).

UserMaintenanceView.xaml

```
     <myProject:UserAutoComplete ViewModel="{Binding ViewModel}" SelectedItem="{max:ValidationBinding SelectedCandidate}" IsRequired="True"/>
```

UserAutoComplete.xaml

```
        <Controls:AutoCompleteTextBox
                        FontSize="11"
                        x:Name="PART_AutoCompleteTextBox"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Controls:UserAutoComplete}}, Converter={StaticResource UserSelectorConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Type Entities:User}, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
                        Text="{Binding ViewModel.Text, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Controls:UserAutoComplete}}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.AutoCompleteItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Controls:UserAutoComplete}}}"
                        SearchCommand="{Binding ViewModel.AutoCompleteSearchCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Controls:UserAutoComplete}}}"
                        IsRequired="{TemplateBinding IsRequired}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        IsItemSelected="{Binding ViewModel.IsItemSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Controls:UserAutoComplete}}}"
                        IsPickerOpen="{Binding ViewModel.IsPickerOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Controls:UserAutoComplete}}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        IsListOpen="{Binding ViewModel.IsListOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Controls:UserAutoComplete}}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        Focusable="True"
                        Behaviours:TextCapitalizationBehaviorBinding.TextCapitalization="Title"
                        IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}"
                        DisplayMember="DisplayName">

                        <Controls:AutoCompleteTextBox.AutoCompleteColumns>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn UniqueName="DisplayName" Header="Name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding DisplayName}" DataType="{x:Type System:String}" Width="0.4*">
                                <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate> 
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName, Mode=OneTime}" Behaviours:HighlightTextBehaviorBinding.Regex="{Binding 
                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Controls:UserAutoComplete}},  
                                            Converter={StaticResource RegexEscapeConverter}, 
                                            Path=ViewModel.LastAutoCompleteSearchText}"  />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Date of birth" DataMemberBinding="{Binding DateOfBirth}" DataType="{x:Type System:String}" Width="Auto">
                                <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding DateOfBirth, StringFormat=' {0:d} ', Mode=OneWay}"  >
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Suburb" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Suburb}" DataType="{x:Type System:String}" Width="Auto">
                                <telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Suburb, Mode=OneWay}"  >
                                        </TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </telerik:GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
                        </Controls:AutoCompleteTextBox.AutoCompleteColumns>
```

Now, I want to modify the WIDTH of the column and the BACKGROUNDCOLOR of the header of the telerik GridViewDataColums for the particular View only.

Needless to say, theres a lot of other view also using the UserAutoComplete so definitely touching the UserAutoComplete code is not the ideal solution.

So here comes the dependency property. My question is what should i use, The normal dependency property or the Attached dependency? And where to put the dependency property, on the UserControl or can i put it in the View?

something like this...

```
public class UserAutoComplete : AutoComplete
{

    public int WidthOfGridDataColumn
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(WidthOfGridDataColumnProperty); }
        set { SetValue(WidthOfGridDataColumnProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for WidthOfGridDataColumn.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty WidthOfGridDataColumnProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("WidthOfGridDataColumn", typeof(int), typeof(ownerclass), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));



    public string BackgroundColorOfGridHeader
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(BackgroundColorOfGridHeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BackgroundColorOfGridHeaderProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BackgroundColorOfGridHeader.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundColorOfGridHeaderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundColorOfGridHeader", typeof(string), typeof(ownerclass), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));`
```

Thanks in advance.